# Trying to access other files in same folder but getting files outside folder

Tags: excel, file, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to access all the other files in the same folder as the program but it wants to go to files in the entire directory. I get that's basically what I'm telling it to do but I'm still new to vba and don't know the syntax to accomplish what I want. Is there a way that I can get the current folder location from the program and have it go through all the files only in that folder?

Also I'd need a solution that doesn't use the Scripting.Object stuff since I'm running into issues with needing to downloading stuff for that and I feel uncomfortable requiring the people that will use this tool download things too especially since they'll be on secure .mil computers (as opposed to .com computers)

```
directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Also tried CurDir()
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
Do While fileName <> ""
   ...
   fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Scripting.FileSystemObject is WINDOWS scripting, you shouldn't need to download anything.   Although you know back 2000 VBS had a pretty nasty worm built from it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILOVEYOU --- Anyways, what I'm getting at is that if you want to make your program secure (since you mentioned the mil thing) you should really use VSTO to develop an add-in for excel, and not write VBA code. But since you're new to VBA and possibly programming that may be out of the question!

Comment: @CodyG. This particular thing I'm programming doesn't deal with anything top secret, just administrative/organizational stuff but it will still but used on the secure computers hence why I want it to work just with default excel stuff. I made a post before and when that stuff was suggested it gave me errors and when I asked I was shown to a instruction thing that said I needed to install those references.

Comment: "install a reference" is a bit of a misnomer, it's a generally a reference to a file already on your PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ThisWorkbook.Path 
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path ' Make sure its the right path...
```

and

```
Filename = Dir(directory & "\" & "*.xl??")
```

Comment: I'll try it when I get back from lunch

Comment: It's still giving me the same issue. Is it my starting place? Because the first file it tries every time is outside the folder so I don't even know it works with the inside files

Comment: @WalterC  I was quite confused how it wasn't working for you as I tested it on my PC. The only other thing I can think of is using ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: Ok it seems to actually being going into the folder now. Thanks. Yeah I was confused too because everywhere I looked I had pretty much the exact same thing everyone else did. Some problems might have been because I thought you meant the second fileName = instead of the first